# Which method improves the performance?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

Suppose I have multiple users.

Which of the following method will improve the performance if I have to process all user's data?

1. Database hit for every user to fetch the filtered data of that user or
2. Fetch data of all user in the single database hit and the filter the data using expression/loops like LAMBDA or LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your data.

if it is small than load it all and process it in a loop/stream 
if it is very big than it is best to combine, 
load a chunk of data process it and load a new chunk, process it and so on,
The issue is that loading from a DB takes time (open connection etc) but loading the entire DB to the memory is also problematic (if it is big), so you need to combine the two options.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks.I have to filter small amount of data for multiple user.So its better(fast in terms of performance) way to fetch all required data once and do manipulation using loops or similar options.

Comment: if the data is not so big and the amount of users is not too huge, than you can load the entire data to memory and process it. 
or even better use a cursor to iterate over the collection